# Express.js TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Tags: node.js, database, express, sqlite

I'm trying to setup a express server, that was already working before. But when I wrote some functionalities on a file, it begun to crash because of a specified property.

The file(index.js):

```
fs = require('fs')
const path = require('path')
const Sequelize = require ('sequelize')
const config = require('../config/config')
const db = {}
/* const sequelize = require('../databaseConfig');
const { DataTypes } = require('sequelize'); */

/* INICIANDO A INSTÂNCIA DB DO SEQUELIZE */
const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    config.db.database,
    config.db.user,
    config.db.password,
    config.db.options
)
/************* */

fs
    .readdirSync(__dirname) //ler um diretório e passar um array com diferentes arquivos. 
    .filter((file) =>
        file !== 'index.js'
    ) //filtrar cada arquivo que seja equivalente ao "index.js" (não queremos o arquivo "index.js", mas queremos todos os outros arquivos de "models").
    
    /* PARA CADA ARQUIVO QUE FOR ENCONTRADO... */
    .forEach((file) => {
        // VVVV será declarado um modelo que armazenará seu caminho relativo para ser usado com o sequelize.
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes)
        //VVVV setar o nome do db como descrito abaixo.
        db[model.name] = model
    })
    /******* */  

db.sequelize = sequelize //acesso ao objeto sequelize.
db.Sequelize = SequeLize //acesso ao objeto CamelCase do SequeLize. 

module.exports = db
```

The error code(node.js):

```
C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\autiapp-tcc-pedro\servidor\models\index.js:29
        db[model.name] = model
                 ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
    at C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\autiapp-tcc-pedro\servidor\models\index.js:29:18
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\autiapp-tcc-pedro\servidor\models\index.js:25:6)   
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)   
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\pedro\OneDrive\Documentos\GitHub\autiapp-tcc-pedro\servidor\app.js:5:21)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Can somebody help me? Thanks!

I tried to import the variable before the function, but It didn't work either.

Comment: seems the "model" inside the foreach function is being undefined, which can mean that  the require function is not loading it properly. But I don't think it is an issue with the "require", eg. with the directory path, because the error would be on the require itself.

Answer (score 2):

The solution here is dependent on the files you have in your directory. I don't know what those files are so the best answer I can give you is to help you debug your code.

`TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading ...)` is a common error in javascript. It means you're trying to access a property on an object, but that the object is `undefined`. In your case, `model` is `undefined`. If you put a `console.log('This is my model ---', model)` statement right before the line with `db[model.name] = model`, you'll see what I mean. This might be happening with the first file in the array of files. It could be happening with the last file. To know which file(s) are causing this issue, you should also `console.log` the `file` variable. This will help you pinpoint the exact issue.